Difficult algebra problem related to finding a specific value in terms of "$c$" or "$b$"
If $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{b}{c}=\frac{c}{a}$ and $ax^2+bx+c=0$ then the value of $b^2x^4+b^2c^2x^2+2b^2cx^3$ is
A) $c^4$ $\quad$B) $-c$ $\quad$C) $-c^2$ $\quad$D) $b^4$
Can anyone please help me with this algebra problem it has nothing to do with quadratic equation. I tried using the quadratic formula but it did not work. The value of the expression that we need to find is a perfect square. But I don't know how to arrive at the answer. Even though it is not overly complex and do not required advanced concepts it requires a lot of algebraic manipulation.

If $\frac{a}{b} = \frac{b}{c} = \frac{c}{a}$, what does that mean for those coefficients? :-)

They are the coefficients of the equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ they have this relation.

Imagine $a=1$, $b=2$ and try to find $c$ => won't work. Even not with $b=3$, $b=4$, ..., so for which value of $b$ might this work? And what's the corresponding value for $c$? ... off you go! :-)

@Dominique You seem to be assuming that $a,b,c$ are real. If we make that assumption, we end up concluding that $x$ must be complex. So why shouldn't we also consider complex $a,b,c$ as well?

@DavidK true. The determinant is indeed $-3b^2$

Hmm... Im not seeing that it need be any of these.  If we assume $a,b,c$ are real then we get $a= b=c\ne 0$ but this value can be any real value.  $ax^2 + bx + c=0; ax^2 +ax + a=0; x^2 + x + 1=0; x=-\frac 12 \pm \frac {\sqrt 3}2 i$ is a constant value.  But $b^2x^4+b^2c^2x^2+2b^2cx^3=b^2x^4 + b^4x^2 + 2b^3x^3$ can be many possible different values for different values of $b$.  If $b=1$ we get that that equals $1$ which is compatible with $b^4,c^4$ but if $b=10^7$ say we get nothing compatible.

Where did this problem come from? Are you sure you copied it exactly as it was given to you? Is it possible that the actual problem is supposed to be slightly different -- something that actually has a solution, for example?

HINT
$$b^2x^2(x^2+c^2+2cx)=(bc(x+c))^2$$
Now $$\frac{b^2}{c}=a=\frac{c^2}{b}\implies b^3=c^3$$
This leads to $3$ cases.
Case 1
$$b=c=a$$
Thus $$bx^2+bx+b=0 \implies x=\frac{-1±\sqrt 3 i}{2}=\omega,\omega^2 \\\implies (x+b)^2=b^2+\omega^2 +2b\omega$$
Or
$$(x+b)^2=b^2+\omega+2b\omega$$
This returns a value in the final expression that can't be simplified further.
Case 2
$b=c\omega, a=c\omega ^2$
Equation becomes $$\omega^2x^2+\omega x+1=0$$
Treating $\omega x=t$, we get $x=1,\omega$.
Sadly none of these return an expression without $\omega$
Case 3
$b=c\omega^2,a=c\omega$
Then
$$\omega x^2 +\omega^2 x + 1=0$$
You can try solving it by quadratic method. It doesn't give the desired answer in the form of $b$ or $c$.
It seems your question is wrong. Firstly, option $2$ and $3$ can be ticked off assuming $bc(x+c)\in\mathbb{R}$.
If $$b^2c^2(x+c)^2=b^4 \text{or} \ c^4$$ then the value of $x$ we get doesn't satisfy original equation.

$b = c$ or $b = c \exp(i2\pi/3)$ or $b = c \exp(-i2\pi/3).$

@DavidK hmm I omitted the complex values for some simplicity. Should I add it?

I also assumed real values until I realized that $x$ cannot then be real. The original question is unclear about this.

@DavidK even if you take real, it gives $x=\omega,\omega^2$ haha :)

None of these answers must work.
Let $m =\frac ab =\frac bc =\frac ac$.  We therefore that none of $a,b,c$ is equal to $0$ and that:
$b= mc$
$a=mb = m^2 c$
$c=ma= m^2 b = m^3 c$.
ANd therefore $m^3 = 1$. So $m$ is a cube root of $1$.  Now there are $3$ cube roots of $3$.  One of them is the real $1$ of course and the other are the complex $\omega_1 = -\frac 12 + \frac {\sqrt 3}2 i$ and $\omega_1= -\frac 12 -\frac{\sqrt 3}2 i$.
It's worth noting that for any cube root $w$ that $w^3=1$ implies $w^2=\frac 1w$ and $(w^2)^3= w^6 = 1$ so $w^2$ is also as square root.  So to restate.  Then three cube roots of $1$ are
$\omega = -\frac 12 + \frac {\sqrt 3}2i=\frac 1{\omega^2}$
$\omega^2 = -\frac 12 -\frac {\sqrt 3}2i = \frac 1{\omega}$
$\omega^3 = 1$.
Now $ax^2 + bx + c=0$ so be the quadratice formula $x =\frac {-b\pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}2=$
$\frac {-cm \pm \sqrt{(mc)^2 -4(m^2)c\cdot c}}{2(m^2c)}=$
$\frac {-cm \pm \sqrt{-3m^2c^2}}{2m^2c}=$
$\frac {-cm \pm cm\sqrt 3i}{2m^2c}=\frac 1m(\frac 12 \pm \frac {\sqrt 3}2i)$.
Note $\frac 12 \pm \frac {\sqrt 3}2i=\omega$ or $\omega^2$ and $\frac 1m$ is a cube root of one,  so $x^3 =1$ so $x$ is a cube root of $1$.
So $m$ and $x$ are both cube roots of $3$.
It holds that either

$m=1; x\ne 1$ and $a=b=c$
$x=1; m\ne 1$ and $a=m^2c;b=mc$
$m=x\ne 1$
$m\ne x;m\ne 1;x\ne 1$ and $m =x^2=\frac 1x$ and $x = m^2=\frac 1m$

Okay... lets attack $b^2x^4+b^2c^2x^2+2b^2cx^3$
$b^2x^4+b^2c^2x^2 + 2b^2cx^3=c^2m^2x^4 + c^4m^2x^2 + 2m^2c^3x^3=c^2m^2x +c^4m^2x^2 +2m^2c^3$
Of $m=1$ and $x = w\ne 1$ but $w^3=1$ we have that equaling
$$c^2w + c^4w^2 + 2c^3$$
which does not reduce to any of your choices.
If $x=1$ and $m=w\ne 1$ but $w^3 =1$ we have
$$c^2w^2 +c^4w^2 +2w^2c^3$$
Ditto.
If $m=x=w\ne 1$ we have
$$c^2 +c^4w +2w^2c^3$$
And if $m\ne x;m\ne 1;x\ne 1$ we have $m=w;x=\frac 1w$
$$c^2w +c^4 +2w^2c^3$$
Of course we can express these in terms of $b$ or $a$ if we wish.

If you don't mind, what game does that cat in your profile picture belong to?

Let $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{b}{c}=\frac{c}{a}=k$
$\implies a=bk,b=ck,c=ak$ 
$\implies c=ck^3$ 
$\implies k^3=1$ 
$\implies k=1,\omega,\omega^2$

It should be specified in the problem whether $a,b,c$ are real or not. Anyways I am assuming that they are real, you can solve for the other cases yourself if you wish.

We have $a=b=c=h\:\:\operatorname{(say)}$
So we have, $x^2+x+1=0$ 
$\implies x=\omega,\omega^2$
$b^2x^4+b^2c^2x^2+2b^2cx^3=h^2 x^4+h^4 x^2+2h^3 x^3$
This comes out to be 
$2h^3+h^4\omega^2+h^2\omega$
The above expression is a complex number unless $h=-1,0,1$

In a nutshell, the question is wrong.
